# Problemas ao utilizar o "using" para acessar métodos estáticos

Tags: c#, static, using

Criei em C# uma classe estática com os métodos `Decode()` e `Encode()` como no código abaixo:

```
namespace Crypt {
    public static class CaesarCipher {
        public static string Decode(string text, byte key) {
            // Meu código...
        }
        public static string Encode(string text, byte key) {
            // Meu código...
        }
    }
}
```

No meu código principal — arquivo `Program.cs` — eu estou tentando simplificar a chamada desses métodos utilizando a diretiva `using`.

Na minha primeira tentativa, eu tentei criar um alias da seguinte forma:

```
using Decode = Crypt.CaesarCipher.Decode;
using Encode = Crypt.CaesarCipher.Encode;
```

O problema é que o compilador gera o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Program.cs(29,26): error CS1001: Identificador esperado
> ```

Lendo a documentação, descobri sobre o uso do `using static`, que serve justamente para acessar os membros estáticos de um tipo sem precisar qualificar o acesso com o nome do mesmo. Tentei aplicá-lo ao meu código, dessa forma:

```
using static Crypt.CaesarCipher.Decode;
using static Crypt.CaesarCipher.Encode;
```

No entanto, novamente o compilador gerou um erro:

> ```
> Program.cs(29,19): error CS0106: O modificador "static" não é válido para este item
> ```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve importar estaticamente a classe e não o método:

```
using static Crypt.CaesarCipher;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => Decode("", 0);
}

namespace Crypt {
    public static class CaesarCipher {
        public static string Decode(string text, byte key) => "";
        public static string Encode(string text, byte key) => "";
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8fXTBR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MrASB2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/UsingStatic.cs).